# SwipeRefreshLayout Issues When Using emptyView and ListView

Tags: android, listview, swiperefreshlayout

I'm using a SwipeRefreshLayout wrapped around a ListView. When the ListView is empty, I've set a TextView to appear. This 'works' fine, but when the ListView is empty and the empty view is showing, the SwipeRefreshLayout doesn't display right. If you drag down, no circle comes down but when you release your finger the circle flashes on the screen and then disappears. If you just touch the screen anywhere, in fact, the SwipeRefreshLayout will appear in the same fashion. The following is how I've defined it in my XML:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/empty_view_requests"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
        android:id="@+id/buddy_requests_swipe_layout">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/buddy_requests_listview"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/norequests_textview"
        android:text="No buddy requests."/>
</FrameLayout>
```

**EDIT:** Activity Code

```
swipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout)findViewById(R.id.buddy_requests_swipe_layout);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.lb_green, R.color.lb_orange, R.color.lb_purple);
    swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            VolleyBuddies.makeGetBuddyRequestsAPICall(BuddyRequestsActivity.this, BuddyRequestsActivity.this);
        }
    });
    FrameLayout noRequestsLayout = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.empty_view_requests);
    ListView requestsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.buddy_requests_listview);
    requestListAdapter = new BuddyRequestsActivityListAdapter(this, this);
    requestsListView.setAdapter(requestListAdapter);
    requestsListView.setEmptyView(noRequestsLayout);
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please add the activity code.

Comment: i added the activity code

Answer (score 1):

I am pasting working code of mine.Even I have faced the issues. hope this will works for you.
 Initially set the emptyview visibility View.GONE.and then on the API Call response callBacks, if there are no items/statuscode..etc ,setvisibility View.VISIBLE and set it as emptyviewfor listview.

```
findViewById(R.id.lvemptyview).setVisibility(View.GONE);



    mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
             if (Utils.isInternetConnected(getApplicationContext())) {
                        CallAPICall(lat, lng);
                        mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                    } }});
```

on volley response callback

```
 mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);

            if (statuscode== 200) {
                try {

                    String content = new String(arg2, "UTF-8");
                    MemberResp memberResp;
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    Type type = new TypeToken<MemberResp>() {
                    }.getType();
                        memberResp = gson.fromJson(content, type);
                        if (memberResp.Status == 1) {

                            if (memberResp.bar_lists.size() > 0) {
                                      findViewById(R.id.lvemptyview).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                          setadapter();
                  } else {

               Adapter.ClearAll();
                          findViewById(R.id.lvemptyview).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                             lvList.setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.lvemptyview));


                            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try placing your `TextView` inside a `ScrollView`. I found that the `SwipeRefreshLayout` requires a scrollable view of some sort

Your code would be

```
<FrameLayout
android:id="@+id/empty_view_requests"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
    android:id="@+id/buddy_requests_swipe_layout">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/buddy_requests_listview"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        />
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:id="@+id/norequests_textview"
        android:text="No buddy requests."/>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Should work right away

Answer (score 0):

You have set your parent framelayout as an empty view of the child(listview). Try removing that line.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work either :( i didn't remove the line, i just made the child (textview) the empty view instead of the parent

Comment: is there any particular reason you used framelayout? Can you use a linear layout instead?

Answer (score 0):

Empty layout is text view.  Please refer following code. and set adapter after SetEmptyListView.

```
TextView noRequestsLayout = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.norequests_textview);
    ListView requestsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.buddy_requests_listview);
    requestListAdapter = new BuddyRequestsActivityListAdapter(this, this);
    requestsListView.setEmptyView(noRequestsLayout);
     requestsListView.setAdapter(requestListAdapter);
```

Comment: @Brandon set adapter after set emptyview